# No results from require php

Tags: php, require

I have file structure like so:

```
root  
-folderA/file1  
--folderB/file2  
---folderC/file3  
----folderD/file4
```

In `file2`, I use `require('../file1')` and it works fine. However, in `file4`, I use `require('../../../file1')` and there is no output.

I have checked the path to make sure `file_exists` and `is_readable`. I used:

```
try{ }catch(exception){ }
```

with no results.

I then copy-pasted my source code in `file2` (knowing that it works) into `file4`, changing only the relative path. No output again.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you turned error_reporting on? Maybe an error occurs before the desired output.

Comment: did you try '/folderA/file1' (on any case I wouldn't recomend to use ../ on complex structures

Comment: and are you calling file 4 directly or are you requiring it from somewhere else?

Comment: @Saikios I did try hard-coding the path. No success.

Comment: @Doon I am calling file4 directly

Comment: @user1911574 thank you. I displayed errors and traced the problem to a different required file having an incorrect relative path. Work from directory folderB but not folderD.